# wget - Save download to one file and download progress to another

Tags: wget

My scripts downloads a list of URLs and saves it to one file. I do some processing on the downloaded content and then move to the next list.
This is how I'm downloading the list of URLs using wget:

```
wget --max-redirect=0 -i $1 -O $2
```

There are multiples URL in the list that are redirected but I don't want to downloaded the redirected URLs, instead I just want to save that URL to a file.
One way to do that is to save the progress of wget to a file and later process it to find which URLs were redirected.

I have tried following but it doesn't work:

```
wget --max-redirect=0 -i $1 -O $2 > progressfile
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the [`-o` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Logging-and-Input-File-Options) (which is distinct from the [`-O` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Download-Options) that you're already using):

```
wget --max-redirect=0 -i $1 -O $2 -o progressfile
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I know I'm a few years late in replying but this helped me a lot since then :)